# |matrix A| = 1 , ||vector B|| = 1 ➜ ||A x B|| always = 1?

Tags: matrices, vectors, determinant

Matrix `A` is a 3x3 matrix.
Vector `B` is a tuple of (x,y,z).

In my real application, `A` is a normal matrix, and `B` is a normal vector.

I know that :-

- Det of `A` = 1
- Size of `B` = `||B||` = `sqrt(B.x ✖ B.x + B.y ✖ B.y + B.z ✖ B.z)` = 1

Is `||A x B||`  always `1`?
Please prove or contradict it by an example.

If this is true, I will be able to optimize a 3D model loader for Opengl.

If it is true, is it possible to extend the theory to any sizes of matrix/vector?

I think I should change the vector B to a 3x3 matrix to make it easier to prove.

I am new to Math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. See for instance $A=\begin{pmatrix}\frac12&0&0\\ 0&6&0\\ 0&0&\frac13\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Thank. I am sad.

Comment: @cppBeginner If your matrix also happens to be orthogonal (which means that $A^T A$ is the identity matrix), then it is true that $A$ preserves length. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_rotation_group

Comment: @Peter Oberly :: Thank, it is very useful.  My situation is not lucky enough.  Time to spam CPU for square-root.  :)